# Local State variable not changing CSS in Next.js upon page load?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

So I have a variable in localStorage that is changed upon using a toggle button. When I click the toggle button it correctly changes the color. However, upon refreshing the page it does not respect the color in local storage.

I'm even logging the variable and it's the correct variable - it's just not respecting it in CSS for some reason. Here's the code:

```
export const Home: React.VFC<any> = () => {
  const theme = useRecoilValue<any>(themeAtom); // gets theme value from the store, which is synced with a localstorage effect

  console.log('theme context from home: ', theme) // dark
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`fixed top-0 left-0 h-full w-1/2 bg-${
          theme === 'dark' ? 'black' : 'white' // renders as white
        }
        `}
      />
...
```

The strange thing is, this technique is working for different contexts, like the user context or authentication context. However, specifically for CSS this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the TailwindCSS JIT engine works, if you're using `bg-${/* ... */}`, TailwindCSS **will not** detect that class and won't include it in your final build. [Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth)

Instead, include `bg` in your ternary so Tailwind can detect the class and add it.

```
<div
  className={`fixed top-0 left-0 h-full w-1/2 ${
    theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-black' : 'bg-white'
    }
  `}
/>
```

Comment: I changed it as you mentioned, but that still didn't fix it. I have a `<select />` that's also using the `theme` value to display the current theme and this works fine. It's just the bg color that is not working

Comment: Could you go to devtools and check if `bg-black` is displayed as a class in the div? And also check at the bottom if the `bg-black` class appears.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Think local-storage is not available in server side and thus not rendering the HTML correctly, what is frustrating that at client side, variables resolved correctly but somehow its not updating/hydrating the html.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).